# How to run delete sql query with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to run a delete sql query with multiple values in it. But I am unable to do so. So need your help on this.

In controller.php page:

```
function deleteFiles()
{
$mainframe = &JFactory::getApplication();
if ($this->_model->deleteFiles()) {
$mainframe->enqueueMessage('Files deleted successfully');
} else {
$mainframe->enqueueMessage('Files not deleted');
}
    ARequest::redirectList($this->_controllerName);
}
```

In model.php page:

```
function deleteFiles($field, $value)
{
$query = 'DELETE FROM ' . $this->rquote($this->_table->getTableName()) . ' WHERE ' . $this->rquote($field) . ' = ' . $this->_db->Quote($value);
$this->_db->setQuery($query);
return $this->_db->query();
}
```

In file.php page

```
function deleteFiles()
{
$this->_db->setQuery('DELETE r 
            FROM #__booking_reservation AS r 
            WHERE r.state = ' . FILES_ACCEPT);
$this->_db->query();
return true;
}
```

Now in file.php page, I want to add FILES_BOOKED, FILES_CANCEL, FILES_DELETE along with the present FILES_ACCEPT. But I don't know how to do it.

Can you help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply define it in your `SQL` query under `WHERE` adding each case with `OR`

```
DELETE r 
FROM #__booking_reservation AS r 
WHERE r.state = .. OR r.state = .. OR ...
```

**Update**

```
$this->_db->setQuery('DELETE r 
        FROM #__booking_reservation AS r 
        WHERE r.state=' .FILES_ACCEPT. ' OR r.state=' .FILES_BOOKED);
```

Comment: Where I am going to put single quote and first bracket?  $this->_db->setQuery('DELETE r 
            FROM #__booking_reservation AS r 
            WHERE r.state = ' . FILES_ACCEPT OR r.state = FILES_DELETE);

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
. . . 
WHERE r.state IN (' . FILES_ACCEPT . ', ' . FILES_BOOKED . ', ' FILES_CANCEL . ', ' . FILES_DELETE . ')' );
```

This assumes that the all-caps names contain valid values for `state`.